# Syntax for specifying Metaclasses in Hy

Tags: python, hy

What is the syntax for for specifying metaclasses in Hy. I tried the following:

```
(defclass Metaclass [] )

(defclass Foo [ :meta Metaclass ] )
(defclass Foo [ [:meta Metaclass] ] )
```

but this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way you would in Python.

This is on Python 3 and the latest master of Hy, and using the `--spy` option in the repl to show the Python compilation.

```
=> (defclass Foo [:metaclass print])
class Foo(metaclass=print):
    pass


None

Foo () {'__module__': '__console__', '__qualname__': 'Foo'}
```

On Python 2.

```
=> (defclass Foo []
...  (setv __metaclass__ print))
class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = print


None

Foo () {'__module__': '__console__', '__metaclass__': <built-in function print>}
```

If you need it to work for either, you could try installing the `six` compatibility library.